# How are case member values stored?

Tags: swift, enums

if case member values are "fully-fledged values in their own right"(apple docs), how are they accessed via dot notation with the value name? Simple example:

```
enum Suit: String {
case clubs, spades, diamonds, hearts

}
var cardInHand = Suit.hearts
print(cardInHand) //prints hearts
```

I'm not confused about how the values are accessed via the enum name (seems like static is implemented behind the scenes). To me `Suit.hearts = hearts` means that a member named hearts stores a value named hearts. In this case, there is only one hearts declared as case hearts. Does this mean the value of the case is implicitly set to the declared value hearts, or the other way around, hearts in case hearts is actually the value but its implicitly set to a static property of the same name? Is hearts in case hearts the value or the name for the value hearts? How can it be both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike enums in other languages, the named labels do not implicitly map to 0, 1.. etc. enum members are their own values of the type specified by the enum's name. Enumerations can store values of any type, and   type values can be different for every enum member.
Refer [this](http://brettbukowski.github.io/SwiftExamples/examples/enums/)

Comment: Yes I understand that it doesn't map to integers but it doesn't make sense that the name labels are the values themselves or are they?

Comment: @User9123 Yep, they are if they are of type `String`.

Comment: @ColGraff thats when assigning raw values. What about when no raw values are assigned like the example above?

Comment: @User9123 An `enum` that has a `rawValue` type of `String` will have a default `rawValue` of its name unless it's assigned something different in the `enum`.

Comment: @User9123, Thats true. And also you do not need to explicity decalre String type on your enum unless you are not assigning any value.

Comment: If thats true then are string values implicitly assigned to basic enum types. (Since the values are printed when you access the case labels)

Comment: @ColGraff so enums implicitly have a rawValue type of string?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, [join me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150511/how-are-case-member-values-stored)

Comment: @HussainShabbir I just tested it out with accessing it with Suit.hearts.rawValue and it yields an error which means String is not implicitly defined.so its not true...

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, What I wanted to explain is you do not need to call rawValue explicitly unless you have not assigned any value inside enum.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your main concern is about why you can get String representations of enum cases.

First of all, it is not the `rawValue` of the enum case. You can see with the following example:

```
enum SuitSymbol: String {
    //Please use a browser which can show emojis
    case clubs = "♣️", spades = "♠️", diamonds = "♦️", hearts = "❤️"
}
var cardInHandSymbol = SuitSymbol.hearts
print(cardInHandSymbol) //prints hearts, not ❤️
print(cardInHandSymbol.rawValue) //prints ❤️
```

The details of this behavior would be so long, that you should check the source code of Swift by yourself:

[Print.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Print.swift)
[OutputStream.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift)

It's hard to go deeper, but you can see that `print` generates enum case's String representations using some hidden function `_getEnumCaseName`.

So, case names are sort of runtime-type-information, as you can get type names using `print`:

```
print(Suit.self) //-> Suit
```

---

A little info about thinking *enum values* in Swift.

To check actual content (byte sequence) stored in a variable, `Data.init(bytes:count:)` is a good tool:

```
var i: Int = 640
print(Data(bytes: &i, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size) as NSData) //-><80020000 00000000>
//0x0280 is the hexadecimal representation of decimal `1000` and it's stored in little endian order.
```

Make it work on Swift enums:

```
print(MemoryLayout<SuitSymbol>.size) //-> 1

print(Data(bytes: &cardInHandSymbol, count: MemoryLayout<SuitSymbol>.size) as NSData) //-> <03>

cardInHandSymbol = .clubs
print(Data(bytes: &cardInHandSymbol, count: MemoryLayout<SuitSymbol>.size) as NSData) //-> <00>

cardInHandSymbol = .spades
print(Data(bytes: &cardInHandSymbol, count: MemoryLayout<SuitSymbol>.size) as NSData) //-> <01>

cardInHandSymbol = .diamonds
print(Data(bytes: &cardInHandSymbol, count: MemoryLayout<SuitSymbol>.size) as NSData) //-> <02>
```

Seems Swift uses only 1 byte to store an internal value for `SuitSymbol` and actually stored values are 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 and 0x03, representing `.clubs`, `.spades`, `.diamonds` and `.hearts` respectively.

Both `rawValue`s and case names seem to be associated with internal values using some data and code embedded in the compiled runtime.

(Internal representation of Swift enums may change in the near future, until Swift Team declares the stability of Swift ABI.)

---

To explain what `static` means as in comments, the following code will tell you better than words:

```
struct SuitStruct: RawRepresentable, CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    private var __internalValue: UInt8

    private init(__internalValue: UInt8) {
        self.__internalValue = __internalValue
    }

    internal static let __caseNames = ["clubs", "spades", "diamonds", "hearts"]
    internal static let __rawValues = ["♣️", "♠️", "♦️", "❤️"]

    static let clubs = SuitStruct(__internalValue: 0)
    static let spades = SuitStruct(__internalValue: 1)
    static let diamonds = SuitStruct(__internalValue: 2)
    static let hearts = SuitStruct(__internalValue: 3)

    var rawValue: String {
        return SuitStruct.__rawValues[Int(__internalValue)]
    }
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        if let internalValue = SuitStruct.__rawValues.index(of: rawValue) {
            self.init(__internalValue: UInt8(internalValue))
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        return SuitStruct.__caseNames[Int(__internalValue)]
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return String(reflecting: SuitStruct.self) + "." + self.description
    }
}
```

The `SuitStruct` behaves very similar to the enum `SuitSymbol`. Of course not exactly the same, but I hope this would help you understanding the background of enum definition.

Comment: Thx. You can say that I'm confused as to whether consider the member value after the case declaration as the type label or the value of the type.

Comment: @User9123, added some info about enum values. Simply saying, in Swift, case names are static member of the enum type. Usually you have no need to go deeper than that.

Comment: I figured that it'd be static but by static member do you mean the name of the static member or the value. For example I read case hearts as static var hearts: [enumType] = hearts. Which hearts (the name or the value) is internally stored and which one is displayed as hearts in case hearts?